# Polya's Enumeration Theorem applied to the 'colourings' of a cycle using integers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to solve a problem about an application to Polya's Enumeration Theorem.
The problem concerns the cycle group on 5 vertices, $C_5$. I found its cycle index to be $x_1^5+4x_5^1$. Thus the corresponding Polya polynomial is: $$\dfrac{1}{5} (x_1^5+4x_5^1)$$.

I am now asked to find how many non-equivalent ways can the cycle be coloured using the integers 0, 1, 2, ... such that the sum of the colours is equal to $5t$, $t \geq 0$.

My idea was to substitute $x_i = (1-x^i)^{-1}$ but I don't know how to extract the coefficient whose power is a multiple of 5. Is this the right way of attacking this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks good to me.  Ignoring leading constants, you have two terms: $(1-x)^{-5}$ and $(1-x^5)^{-1}$, whose series expansions are $\sum_k \binom{k+4}{4}x^k$ and $\sum_k x^{5k}$ respectively.  To get the coefficient of $x^{5t}$, take $k=5t$ in the first sum, and $k=t$ in the second sum.